# gradle RPM publish issue

Tags: jenkins, gradle, nexus, rpm, yum

I am facing issue to upload RPM file to nexus repository with gradle build tool using Jenkins. I am using below code  :

```
 publishing {
  publications {
    rpm(IvyPublication) {
    artifact buildRPM.outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile()
    organisation 'dummy'
     }
  }

  uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        ivy {
            credentials {
                username "username"
                password "password"
            }
            url "https://xyz nexus url"
            layout "pattern", {
               artifact "${buildRPM.outputs.getFiles().getSingleFile().getName()}"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Using above code I am just able to create rpm file name at nexus repository but not able to upload/pulish rpm file. Please anyone help me on it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use and it works for me:

```
publish.dependsOn <rpmBuildTaskName>
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url <nexusRepoToPublishTo>
            credentials {
                username "username"
                password "password"
        }
    }

    publications {
        jar(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId "<artifactNameString>"
            artifact "${buildDir}/libs/<jarName>"
        }
        rpm(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId "<artifactNameString>"
            artifact "${buildDir}/distributions/<nameOfTheRPM>"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I posted uses the "maven-publish" plugin as well